# How to convert all percentage data in R to decimal?

Tags: r, percentage

I have a large data set containing both numerical and categorical data.
A number of columns contain % data i.e. "26.2%", as these are not recognised in R as percentages I wish to convert them to decimals.

I have tried:

```
data2 <- as.numeric(sub("%", "",data,fixed=TRUE))/100
```

However:

> Warning message:
>   NAs introduced by coercion

Can someone please help with the correct approach and/or syntax?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your data is a dataframe, you can not use the sub function.
sub is for vectors.

Try using the same function but column by column
e.g.

```
column1 <- as.numeric(sub("%", "",data$column1,fixed=TRUE))/100
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. I have 400+ columns though, is there a way to do something similar across a df?

Comment: maybe a dirty solution, but you can always do that with a loop:  for(i in 1:ncol(data)){
data[,i] <- as.numeric(sub("%", "",data[,i],fixed=TRUE))/100
}

Comment: Thanks everyone, I don't have enough rep to Vote Up, but all helpful suggestions. Cheers

Answer (score 3):

You could try:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% mutate_each(funs(as.numeric(gsub("%", "", ., fixed = TRUE))/100))
```

Answer (score 2):

To apply to all columns you can combine the code provided by the other users with an apply statement. For example,

```
apply(d,2, function(x){
 as.numeric(sub("%", "", x, fixed=TRUE))/100}
```

*where* `d` is your dataframe